# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException No signature of method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, classpath

I am getting this error, and when I changed the method to getClassPathList().get(0) to getClassPath() as was suggested in possible solutions. Now I get the same error telling to use the getClassPathList() instead. I'm confused !
Code:

Original code:

```
myReader(groovyObject.getPackageInfo().getReference().getClassPathList().get(0), value1, value2)
```

changed code:

```
myReader(groovyObject.getPackageInfo().getReference().getClassPath(), value1, value2)
```

Error message:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: myapplication.x.y.z.GroovyClassReference.getClassPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getClassName(), getClass(), getClassPathList(), setClassName(java.lang.String)

Comment: "_as was suggested in possible solutions_" what suggested to use a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: can you post the first error you had when you were using `getClassPathList().get(0)`?